# Self sizing table view cells based on ui stack view content

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview, stackview

i want to create cells with stack view in it. For different cells there would be different amount of arranged subviews in stack view.

Currently i create something like this but self sizing isn't working.

Table view initialization:

```
    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        return tableView
    }()
```

Table view cell:

```
import UIKit

final class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        return stackView
    }()

   // initializations...

    private func setup() {
        backgroundColor = .green

        addSubviewsWithConstraints([stackView])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)

        ])

        stackView.addArrangedSubviews([CustomView(), CustomView()])
        // custom views will be added later depends on model
    }
}
```

Custom view:

```
final class CustomView: UIView {

    private let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")
        return imageView
    }()

    //MARK: - Override

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        addSubviewsWithConstraints([iconImageView])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            iconImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 6),
            iconImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 6),
            iconImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80),
            iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80)
        ])
    }
}
```

To add subviews i'm using custom extension to uiview:

```
    func addSubviewWithConstraints(_ view: UIView) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func addSubviewsWithConstraints(_ views: [UIView]) {
        views.forEach {
            addSubviewWithConstraints($0)
        }
    }
```

Result looks like this (using 2 cells with 2 custom views in stack views):

[image: table view]

Answer (score 0):

Your `addSubviewsWithConstraint` is adding views as a subview of the cell not as a subview of the contentView. Cells use the contentView for self sizing. As `addSubviewsWithConstraint`  is an extension of `UIView` you should be able to do the following anywhere you want to add a subview to a cell.

```
contentView.addSubviewWithConstraints(...)
```

Just another thing that may be useful is that you can shorten your functions down by using variadic arguments like so:

```
func addSubviewWithConstraints(_ views: UIView...) {
    views.forEach {
        addSubviewWithConstraints($0)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
addSubviewWithConstraints(mySubview)
addSubviewWithConstraints(mySubview, mySubview2, mySubview3)
```

Comment: Im using custom function addSubviewsWithConstraint. I updated the question.

Comment: @michalmichalek Updated my answer in response to your question being updated.

Comment: i used:
contentView.addSubviewsWithConstraints([stackView])

but nothing changed

Comment: Ah my bad if you do that you’ll need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false within the loop on the view.

Comment: I undestand that and im setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false but result is the same. Cells are not self sizing. :(